# Set user loggin status?

Tags: customization, users, functions

I create user with wp_create_user,after succesfully creating a user I need to set his status to be logged in?How to set his status to be logged in ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`wp_signon()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon). Ex:

```
$creds = array();
$creds['user_login'] = 'example';
$creds['user_password'] = 'plaintextpw';
$creds['remember'] = true;

$user = wp_signon( $creds, false );

if ( is_wp_error($user) )
    echo $user->get_error_message();
```

[See Codex for more details about `wp_signon()`.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon)